# How do I fix "Cannot find module" error using Node.js/react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-package

I am working on a website using react.js and tailwindcss. Yesterday ı was starting my project on localhost and everything was fine. I didn't change anything but I can not open my project on localhost now.Error is **Cannot find module**

P.S: Is there another way for preview my project without npm?
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd1r4.png)

[APP.JSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcv7T.png)

I checked other questions and I tried some of solutions but none of them didn't work.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete node_modules and package-lock.json.

Then run:

> npm i

or

> yarn

Comment: It doesnt't work for me. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import App.js somewhere instead importing App.jsx so you are receiving module not found error. Make sure you've imported App.jsx everywhere not as a App.js.